# Contact name not showing name in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, contact-form

I'm a rookie, and looking to create a contact form, but when I check my submitted forms, it doesn't show the name. It just says `name ""` I'm using Ruby on Rails.

My `html` looks like;

> Contact Us

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="well">
    <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :comments %>
        <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My `controller` code looks like;

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
      @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
        redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Message Sent."
    else
        redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Error Occured"
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
   params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
  end
```

end

Comment: can you verify what is sent in the params to your controller? and you have a typo in the email field, it says `f.text_field name` instead of `f.text_field email`

Comment: @Subash thanks for the reply! That was the issue. I was copying and pasting the code for the other text fields, and having the double "names", must have cancelled out the input. Thanks for your help

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your second text field is the problem, it's called :name twice... 
change the second input and try it again

```
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
```

to

```
<%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
```